# ag-grid Grid not visible on iPad Air os 10.1.1

Tags: ag-grid

Current behavior
Grid is not visible as it does not respect the w/h = 100% set in the styles. I am able to see the grid instance after I manually change the h to calc(100%) in dev tools.

Expected behavior
Grid is visible, height of 100%

Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions
Implement AG Grid and view on iPad ios 10.1.1

Please tell us about your environment:
IPad Air, os 10.1.1
ag-grid-angular version: 16.0.0
ag-grid version: 18.0.0
Angular version: 5.x.x

Browser:
Mobile Chrome 55 | iOS 10 Safari

Comment: Same here, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me - the grid worked okay on Windows Chrome and Firefox, but didn't appear on iOS Safari or Chrome.

The problem was there was a div in the hierarchy without a height 100% - I was using flexbox for part of the view.

The solution was to just make sure all the divs containing the ag-grid have `height: 100%`.